# How to Add Callback method & redirect to a page in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect, jquery-callback

I have a function in `JQuery` which shows the `Message in div` to the User on the `ASPX page` at the top of the page. All works fine just i want to `redirect` user to the `URL` that is passed in the function using `Callback'`jquery.

As their is `fadeOut()` to show the `div` i need to redirect only when the `fadeOut()` effect or the animation is completed. and not sudden display of `div`.

**Javascript:**

```
function ShowJPopupTitleCallBack(msg, msgTitle) {
    $("#jDialogMessage").html(msg);
    $("#jDialogMessage").show("slow", function() {

    });
    $("#jDialogMessage").fadeOut(5000);
//window.location="Login.aspx";
    return false;
};
```

**In aspx.cs file:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "<script type='text/javascript'>ShowJPopupTitleCallBack('Sorry! Your session has being expired please login & try again.','Session Timeout...!')</script>");
```

Here, i want to pass one more parameter to `redirect` to the said `url` using jquery only after the messabe is being displayed(animation completed).

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pass the callback inside fadeout method

function ShowJPopupTitleCallBack(msg, msgTitle) {
    $("#jDialogMessage").html(msg);
    $("#jDialogMessage").show("slow", function() {

    });
    $("#jDialogMessage").fadeOut(5000,function(){
         window.location="Login.aspx";
    });
//window.location="Login.aspx";
    return false;
};
```

Comment: yes this works fine! just as information. can we write custom function  for callback in my existing function? thanks!

Comment: Yes you can create your own callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You want the callback to `show()` to trigger the `fadeOut()`, then the callback in `fadeOut()` to perform the redirect...

```
function ShowJPopupTitleCallBack(msg, msgTitle) {
    var dialogMessage = $("#jDialogMessage");
    dialogMessage.html(msg);
    dialogMessage.show("slow", function() {
        dialogMessage.fadeOut(5000, function () {
            window.location="Login.aspx";
        });
    });
    return false;
};
```